# How do forward roll on a specific subset of data and while modifying the original dataset?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I'm trying to perform this operation on this dataset. I'm trying to calculate cummulative Sum of the specific subset of the dataset.I want the changes to reflect on real dataset.
. Table below illustrates how I want to calculate **Offset**.

```
#OFFSET
min = data.exit_block.min() 
max = data.exit_block.max()
temp = 0
data['Offset']
for i in tqdm(range(min,min+10)):
  offset = data.loc[(data["exit_block"] >= i) & (data["entry_block"] < i)]['size'].sum()

  data.loc[data["entry_block"] == i ,'Offset'] = data[data['entry_block']==i]['size'].cumsum() + offset
  print(len(data.loc[(data["exit_block"] >= i) & (data["entry_block"] < i)]['size']))
  print(offset)
  print(data[data['entry_block']==i]['size'].cumsum().head()  )

  print(data[data['entry_block']==i]['size'].head())
  break
```

In the code above I'm creating a **dataset B** from original dataset and trying to perform of the cummulative sum operation on the origial dataset from the values driven from **dataset B.**

| Index | Entry_block | Exit_block | Size | Offset |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 20 | 10 | 10 |
| 2 | 11 | 20 | 150 | 160 |
| 3 | 18 | 20 | 100 | 260 |
| 4 | 19 | 21 | 40 | 300 |
| 5 | 20 | 21 | 120 | 120 |
| 6 | 20 | 21 | 180 | 300 |
| 7 | 20 | 21 | 210 | 510 |
| 8 | 20 | 21 | 90 | 600 |
| 9 | 20 | 21 | 450 | 1050 |

Comment: from your expected output, it looks like you try to do `df['Offset'] = df.groupby('Exit_block')['Size'].cumsum()`?

Comment: doesn't work returns Series([], Name: size, dtype: int64)